# sort alphanumeric values in python with natsort

Tags: python

I am building a script in python3 to sort alphanumeric string like the below:

```
vlan 10
   name RED_t10
vlan 20
   name RED_t20
vlan 30
   name BLUE_t30
vlan 40
   name BLUE_t40
vlan 50
   name GREEN_t50
vlan 60
   name GREEN_t60
vlan 4093
   name LEAF_PEER_L3
   trunk group LEAF_PEER_L3
vlan 4094
   name MLAG_PEER
   trunk group MLAG
vlan 141
   name BLUE_t141
vlan 1141
  name BLUE_t141_TRANSIT
vlan 2141
   name BLUE_t141_EDGE_TRANSIT
vlan 666
   name RED_t666
vlan 1666
  name RED_t666_TRANSIT
```

I have seen different option am using `natsort` and I can see that `vlan 141` is at the bottom while I was expecting  to see between `vlan 60` and `vlan 666`. I have also tried with lambda based on this [link](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/sorting-alphanumeric-strings-in-python/) and I have the same result. So I suspect there is something I am missing. Anyone can help me to understand why this result?

```
for i in natsorted(vlans):
     print(i)

vlan 10
   name RED_t10
vlan 20
   name RED_t20
vlan 30
   name BLUE_t30
vlan 40
   name BLUE_t40
vlan 50
   name GREEN_t50
vlan 60
   name GREEN_t60
vlan 666
   name RED_t666
vlan 1141
  name BLUE_t141_TRANSIT
vlan 1666
  name RED_t666_TRANSIT
vlan 2141
   name BLUE_t141_EDGE_TRANSIT
vlan 2666
   name RED_t666_EDGE_TRANSIT
vlan 4093
   name LEAF_PEER_L3
   trunk group LEAF_PEER_L3
vlan 4094
   name MLAG_PEER
   trunk group MLAG
vlan 141
   name BLUE_t141
```

Comment: We can't tell, from what you've posted, where the boundaries are between the items of the list you're trying to sort.  I suspect that `vlan 141` is actually tacked onto the end of the `vlan 4094` entry, rather than being a separate entry.

Comment: I had never heard of the `natsort` package, thanks for that.  I'll agree with @jasonharper, this can't be solved unless we see the actual structure of the data you're sorting.  `print(repr(vlans))` would help immensely.